# Comparisons in awk

Tags: awk

The following awk code is working as expected. 
I want to check if the second field $2 is 0 and use "setex" command instead of default "hincrby".

```
BEGIN {
    # all fields are separated by ^
    FS = "^";
}
{
    # $7 is the date and time in the form yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.
    # Split at colons to get hours minutes and seconds into a[1]
    # through a[3].  Round minutes to nearest 5.
    split($7, a, ":");
    split(gensub(/-/,"","g",$7),b,"~");
    a[2] = int(a[2]);
    printf "hincrby r:%s:%s %s:%02d:00 1\\r\\n\n zadd RequestSet %s r:%s:%s\\r\\n\n ", $1, $2, a[1], a[2], b[1], $1, $2;
}
```

The above code will output like this...

```
hincrby r:565:14718 2012-03-10~12:55:00 1\r\n zadd RequestSet 20120310 r:565:14718\r\n
```

If the creativeid is 0 then the following output is expected:

```
hincrby r:565:0 2012-03-10~12:55:00 1\r\n zadd RequestSet 20120310 r:565:14718\r\n hincrby r:565:14718 nods 1\r\n
```

For all other creativeids ($2), I need another statement generated with complete date ($7)

```
hincrby r:565:14718 2012-03-10~12:55:00 1\r\n zadd RequestSet 20120310 r:565:14718\r\n setex xyzabc:r 172800 2012-03-10~12:59:49\r\n
```

In other words, I am trying to write the following PHP logic to awk

```
    if($creativeid !=0 ){            
        $pipe->setex($cb.':r','172800',$datetime); 
    }else{
        $pipe->hincrby("r:".$zone.":".$creativeid,'nods',1);  
    }
```

**Update:**

The following if-then-else code does not seem to work:

```
if $2 = 0 
printf "hincrby r:%s:%s %s:%02d:00 1\\r\\n\n zadd RequestSet %s r:%s:%s\\r\\n\n hincrby r:%s:%s nods 1\r\n", $1, $2, a[1], a[2], b[1], $1, $2, $1, $2;
else
printf "hincrby r:%s:%s %s:%02d:00 1\\r\\n\n zadd RequestSet %s r:%s:%s\\r\\n\n setex %s:r 172800 %s", $1, $2, a[1], a[2], b[1], $1, $2, $5, $7;
```

Comment: as in most languages, it's called `if` in awk too. what's your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cmd = (a[2] == 0) ? "hincrby" : "setx"
print cmd    

# or 

if( a[2] == 0 ) print "hincrby"
else print "setx"
```

`a[2]=0` will **always** be true. it is just an assignment...
`a[2]="anything"` will be true unless it it an invalid value.

Note that `if( a[2]=0 )` *does* change the value of `a[2]` ...

Answer (score 0):

if ($2 = 0) solved the problem. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: No.. you're assigning 0 to the second field of your data. TO test if it equals zero, you need to use `if $(2 == 0) ...`. Note the 2 '=' signs.  Good luck.